# Using the c# connector how do I query Snowflake to determine if columns are Virtual Columns?

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake I can use

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE Schema1.Table1;
```

Which will return results that tell me that the kind of column is "COLUMN" or "VIRTUAL" column.

However running the "SHOW COLUMNS" command through the C# connector doesn't seem to be supported.

In C# I can query the tables in the information_schema schema, but none of the tables in that schema seem to have the "kind" information that details the virtual columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you face any errors or just getting empty result, I did a quick test and could retrieve the values as follows:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SHOW COLUMNS IN TABLE T1";
                                                                 
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            
while (reader.Read())
{
Console.WriteLine("column type: "+ reader.GetString(6));
}
```

6 - is the index of the column that has the `kind`

If it does not work for you could you please clarify your question a bit.

Comment: Hmm thanks for trying, looking at the logs I can see it suggests the schema doesn't exist or permission denied. However when I run the query in the Snowflake UI, it seems to work fine (even though I am logged in as the same user in both instances). Thanks for the info, will try further!!

Comment: @Slicc You're welcome. The error means the session context in your c# code is not set exactly as you test it in a worksheet. Check your connection string, you can specify the current role, db, and schema there: ```ROLE=<your_role>;db=<your_db>;schema =<your_schema>```

Comment: Thanks, in the end it was just a connection string error. Thanks again.